# ASP.NET Core - How to upload a zip file if there does not exist a client-side UI for file selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a unique scenario in which I'd like the end result to help me upload a zip file. Here is what is happening in my workflow:

1. Our user is given an application on their local machine. With a click of a button, it will copy files and a zip file to remote-machine-1.
2. On remote-machine-2, it is running a .NET Core web app.
3. On remote-machine-1, I'd like to ping an endpoint off the web app in order to upload the zip file to remote-machine-2. However, the caveat is that the user will not be able to specify where this zip file is - the location of the zip file already known due to the structure of how the files and zip file are copied over in the first place.

So the question remains, with the code below - how do I pass in an IFormFile object when I call the endpoint **localhost:5000/PublishTargetAsync?file=[???]**? Or is there another workaround?

```
    public async Task<bool> PublishTargetAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_targetOutputDirectory.ToFileSystemPath(), file.Name), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: When you say ping...do you mean that the user on machine 1 is browsing to a page on machine 2, or that they are using some un-named application on machine 1? I'm confused.

What is the user doing on machine 1 when you want the specific file uploaded to the server?

Comment: @wllmsaccnt The application running on the local machine will just ping an endpoint on remote-machine-2. Given that remote-machine-2 is hosting the web service. Does that help clarify things a bit?

Comment: So your question is "how do you transfer a file from a desktop application to a web application?"

Comment: @wllmsaccnt I guess that is accurate to say in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but non optimized approach would be to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#sending-a-post-request-to-create-a-resource) and post the file contents as a base64 encoded string as Json using sample code similar to what is in my link. From there you could work your way back to using HttpWebRequests and a network stream and crafting the Http request by hand if necessary for performance, but the above approach should work for most small files. You'll have to modify your PublishTargetAsync endpoint to handle a post request with the right type.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot :)